# Django integration with Bootstrap template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, bootstrap-4

I downloaded Bootstrap theme and integrated it with django, the frontend is perfectly fine but i need help in writing code for its backend integration.

index.html as per dwonloaded template:

```
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8">
    <div class="form">
      <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
      <div id="errormessage"></div>
      <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" title="Send Message">Send Message</button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should be in my models.py file so as to save the received contact data to database.

Comment: Probably you need to read Django tutorial first(1-2 hours): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/ 
1) You'll learn Django; 2) You'll get ideas how to implement what you want

Comment: You have to use django forms to do that. As @Satevg said, you have to read Django documentation in the first step ;)

Answer (score 0):

The models.py file should be see like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    # if the field is required
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # if the fields can be NULL 
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.TextField()
```